# Pasting Javascript code into Slim

Tags: slim-lang

I'm using olark on my site and want to paste their Javascript snippet into my Slim template .. but all hell breaks loose when I do:

```
<!-- begin olark code --> <script data-cfasync="false" type='text/javascript'>/*<![CDATA[*/window.olark||(function(c){var f=window,d=document,l=f.location.protocol=="https:"?"https:":"http:",z=c.name,r="load";var nt=function(){ f[z]=function(){ (a.s=a.s||[]).push(arguments)};var a=f[z]._={ },q=c.methods.length;while(q--){(function(n){f[z][n]=function(){ f[z]("call",n,arguments)}})(c.methods[q])}a.l=c.loader;a.i=nt;a.p={ 0:+new Date};a.P=function(u){ a.p[u]=new Date-a.p[0]};function s(){ a.P(r);f[z](r)}f.addEventListener?f.addEventListener(r,s,false):f.attachEvent("on"+r,s);var ld=function(){function p(hd){ hd="head";return["<",hd,"></",hd,"><",i,' onl' + 'oad="var d=',g,";d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].",j,"(d.",h,"('script')).",k,"='",l,"//",a.l,"'",'"',"></",i,">"].join("")}var i="body",m=d[i];if(!m){ return setTimeout(ld,100)}a.P(1);var j="appendChild",h="createElement",k="src",n=d[h]("div"),v=n[j](d[h](z)),b=d[h]("iframe"),g="document",e="domain",o;n.style.display="none";m.insertBefore(n,m.firstChild).id=z;b.frameBorder="0";b.id=z+"-loader";if(/MSIE[ ]+6/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ b.src="javascript:false"}b.allowTransparency="true";v[j](b);try{ b.contentWindow[g].open()}catch(w){ c[e]=d[e];o="javascript:var d="+g+".open();d.domain='"+d.domain+"';";b[k]=o+"void(0);"}try{ var t=b.contentWindow[g];t.write(p());t.close()}catch(x){ b[k]=o+'d.write("'+p().replace(/"/g,String.fromCharCode(92)+'"')+'");d.close();'}a.P(2)};ld()};nt()})({ loader: "static.olark.com/jsclient/loader0.js",name:"olark",methods:["configure","extend","declare","identify"]}); /* custom configuration goes here (www.olark.com/documentation) */ olark.identify('XXXX-XXX-XX-XXXX');/*]]>*/</script><noscript><a href="https://www.olark.com/site/XXXX-XXX-XX-XXXX/contact" title="Contact us" target="_blank">Questions? Feedback?</a> powered by <a href="http://www.olark.com?welcome" title="Olark live chat software">Olark live chat software</a></noscript> <!-- end olark code -->
```

What to do? I've tried the [HTML2Slim convertor](https://html2slim.herokuapp.com), but that broke too.

There's gotta be a better way, I know it.

Answer (score 1):

As shown on http://slim-lang.com you can write javascript inside slim with 'javascript:'.

So you could do the following:

```
javascript:
  /*<![CDATA[*/window.olark||(function(c){var f=window,d=document,l=f.location.protocol=="https:"?"https:":"http:",z=c.name,r="load";var nt=function(){ f[z]=function(){ (a.s=a.s||[]).push(arguments)};var a=f[z]._={ },q=c.methods.length;while(q--){(function(n){f[z][n]=function(){ f[z]("call",n,arguments)}})(c.methods[q])}a.l=c.loader;a.i=nt;a.p={ 0:+new Date};a.P=function(u){ a.p[u]=new Date-a.p[0]};function s(){ a.P(r);f[z](r)}f.addEventListener?f.addEventListener(r,s,false):f.attachEvent("on"+r,s);var ld=function(){function p(hd){ hd="head";return["<",hd,"></",hd,"><",i,' onl' + 'oad="var d=',g,";d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].",j,"(d.",h,"('script')).",k,"='",l,"//",a.l,"'",'"',"></",i,">"].join("")}var i="body",m=d[i];if(!m){ return setTimeout(ld,100)}a.P(1);var j="appendChild",h="createElement",k="src",n=d[h]("div"),v=n[j](d[h](z)),b=d[h]("iframe"),g="document",e="domain",o;n.style.display="none";m.insertBefore(n,m.firstChild).id=z;b.frameBorder="0";b.id=z+"-loader";if(/MSIE[ ]+6/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ b.src="javascript:false"}b.allowTransparency="true";v[j](b);try{ b.contentWindow[g].open()}catch(w){ c[e]=d[e];o="javascript:var d="+g+".open();d.domain='"+d.domain+"';";b[k]=o+"void(0);"}try{ var t=b.contentWindow[g];t.write(p());t.close()}catch(x){ b[k]=o+'d.write("'+p().replace(/"/g,String.fromCharCode(92)+'"')+'");d.close();'}a.P(2)};ld()};nt()})({ loader: "static.olark.com/jsclient/loader0.js",name:"olark",methods:["configure","extend","declare","identify"]}); /* custom configuration goes here (www.olark.com/documentation) */ olark.identify('XXXX-XXX-XX-XXXX');/*]]>*/
```

Or if the attribute 'data-cfasync="false"' is necessary, you could perhaps write this (but I'm not sure if it works):

```
script data-cfasync="false"
  /*<![CDATA[*/window.olark||(function(c){var f=window,d=document,l=f.location.protocol=="https:"?"https:":"http:",z=c.name,r="load";var nt=function(){ f[z]=function(){ (a.s=a.s||[]).push(arguments)};var a=f[z]._={ },q=c.methods.length;while(q--){(function(n){f[z][n]=function(){ f[z]("call",n,arguments)}})(c.methods[q])}a.l=c.loader;a.i=nt;a.p={ 0:+new Date};a.P=function(u){ a.p[u]=new Date-a.p[0]};function s(){ a.P(r);f[z](r)}f.addEventListener?f.addEventListener(r,s,false):f.attachEvent("on"+r,s);var ld=function(){function p(hd){ hd="head";return["<",hd,"></",hd,"><",i,' onl' + 'oad="var d=',g,";d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].",j,"(d.",h,"('script')).",k,"='",l,"//",a.l,"'",'"',"></",i,">"].join("")}var i="body",m=d[i];if(!m){ return setTimeout(ld,100)}a.P(1);var j="appendChild",h="createElement",k="src",n=d[h]("div"),v=n[j](d[h](z)),b=d[h]("iframe"),g="document",e="domain",o;n.style.display="none";m.insertBefore(n,m.firstChild).id=z;b.frameBorder="0";b.id=z+"-loader";if(/MSIE[ ]+6/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ b.src="javascript:false"}b.allowTransparency="true";v[j](b);try{ b.contentWindow[g].open()}catch(w){ c[e]=d[e];o="javascript:var d="+g+".open();d.domain='"+d.domain+"';";b[k]=o+"void(0);"}try{ var t=b.contentWindow[g];t.write(p());t.close()}catch(x){ b[k]=o+'d.write("'+p().replace(/"/g,String.fromCharCode(92)+'"')+'");d.close();'}a.P(2)};ld()};nt()})({ loader: "static.olark.com/jsclient/loader0.js",name:"olark",methods:["configure","extend","declare","identify"]}); /* custom configuration goes here (www.olark.com/documentation) */ olark.identify('XXXX-XXX-XX-XXXX');/*]]>*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Lol, that was easy enough. Turns out I just had to strip the line breaks and prepend a `'`.

Like so:

```
'<!-- begin olark code --> <script data-cfasync="false" type='text/javascript'>/*<![CDATA[*/window.olark||(function(c){var f=window,d=document,l=f.location.protocol=="https:"?"https:":"http:",z=c.name,r="load";var nt=function(){ f[z]=function(){ (a.s=a.s||[]).push(arguments)};var a=f[z]._={ },q=c.methods.length;while(q--){(function(n){f[z][n]=function(){ f[z]("call",n,arguments)}})(c.methods[q])}a.l=c.loader;a.i=nt;a.p={ 0:+new Date};a.P=function(u){ a.p[u]=new Date-a.p[0]};function s(){ a.P(r);f[z](r)}f.addEventListener?f.addEventListener(r,s,false):f.attachEvent("on"+r,s);var ld=function(){function p(hd){ hd="head";return["<",hd,"></",hd,"><",i,' onl' + 'oad="var d=',g,";d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].",j,"(d.",h,"('script')).",k,"='",l,"//",a.l,"'",'"',"></",i,">"].join("")}var i="body",m=d[i];if(!m){ return setTimeout(ld,100)}a.P(1);var j="appendChild",h="createElement",k="src",n=d[h]("div"),v=n[j](d[h](z)),b=d[h]("iframe"),g="document",e="domain",o;n.style.display="none";m.insertBefore(n,m.firstChild).id=z;b.frameBorder="0";b.id=z+"-loader";if(/MSIE[ ]+6/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ b.src="javascript:false"}b.allowTransparency="true";v[j](b);try{ b.contentWindow[g].open()}catch(w){ c[e]=d[e];o="javascript:var d="+g+".open();d.domain='"+d.domain+"';";b[k]=o+"void(0);"}try{ var t=b.contentWindow[g];t.write(p());t.close()}catch(x){ b[k]=o+'d.write("'+p().replace(/"/g,String.fromCharCode(92)+'"')+'");d.close();'}a.P(2)};ld()};nt()})({ loader: "static.olark.com/jsclient/loader0.js",name:"olark",methods:["configure","extend","declare","identify"]}); /* custom configuration goes here (www.olark.com/documentation) */ olark.identify('XXXX-XXX-XX-XXXX');/*]]>*/</script><noscript><a href="https://www.olark.com/site/XXXX-XXX-XX-XXXX/contact" title="Contact us" target="_blank">Questions? Feedback?</a> powered by <a href="http://www.olark.com?welcome" title="Olark live chat software">Olark live chat software</a></noscript> <!-- end olark code -->
```